# Powershell PSReadLine History

Tags: powershell

I'm confused about how `PSReadLine` history works across sessions in Powershell. I can see in PS version 5.1 my previous command history is automatically stored in

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PSReadline\
```

However, if I run `get-history` I only see my current session command history. I thought hooks to save command history across sessions was no longer needed in later versions of Powershell. What am I missing?

Comment: you may want to take a look at this article ... Better PowerShell History Management with PSReadLine – Hey, Scripting Guy! Blog — https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/06/18/better-powershell-history-management-with-psreadline/

Comment: The answer from LotPings is correct. The `PSReadline` history file and `Get-History` history are two different things.

Comment: Thanks -- So PSReadLine let's me up arrow to see history. I guess I have to go back to using the old way of hooking exit to save and re-import my history. Just seems less than useful to save history but not re-import to new sessions.

Comment: @ChadMiller - no ... you have no need to do that at all! [*grin*]  PSReadLine has all that stored - you simply need to use the **_PSReadLine_** commands, not `Get-History`. review the link i posted for some ideas on how to do that. for instance, `<ctrl><r>` brings up a backward search of the entire history stored by PSReadLine.

Comment: I like `NOTEPAD (Get-PSReadLineOption).HistorySavePath` to view my history

Comment: @NoRefundsNoReturns I like that idea, but cat and sending to ogv. I was looking for a way to search and see ALL my previous commands from command line similar to  "history | grep". Thanks

Comment: substitute `gc` for `NOTEPAD` or better yet use the the many features of PSReadLine (like Up Arrow completion) or Ctrl+R to find previous commands.

Answer (score 9):

The file

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PSReadline\ConsoleHost_history.txt
```

containing only the entered commands (here ATM 22k lines),

and the current sessions history

```
Get-History | Format-List -Property *
```

---

```
Id                 : 88
CommandLine        : get-help Get-History -online
ExecutionStatus    : Completed
StartExecutionTime : 2018-12-14 16:16:49
EndExecutionTime   : 2018-12-14 16:16:49
```

are quite different things.

Answer (score 4):

Get-History accesses the **PowerShell** history (current session only).

PSReadLine uses its own history (in memory and saved in `(Get-PSReadLineOption).HistorySavePath`). Commands entered using PSReadLine are (typically) appended to the history file as they are entered (this behaviour can also be controlled using `Set-PSReadLineOption -HistorySaveStyle`). The various search and navigation keys can then bring any history entry onto the current command line. Note that when accessing history using up-arrow or down-arrow, new commands from concurrent sessions (i.e. commands entered **after** the current session started) are skipped ([design decision](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/commit/49a4c4c1e62a00dc9fda357b0182a0d76d0d3bd9)). However, these commands **can** be accessed by using the history search functions (F8, SHIFT-F8, CTRL-R and CTRL-S). Unfortunately, you can't retrieve the list of commands following the one that you search for by using down-arrow after searching.

If you **really** (desperately) need to access newer commands from other sessions using the arrow keys, you could start a new session but then you would lose (access to) any variables (and newly entered functions) from the current session. One solution could be to use `export-clixml` to transfer some (all?) variables/functions by creating a hashtable keyed by the variable/function's name and then use `import-clixml` and recreate the variables/functions from the resulting hashtable in the new session. However, depending upon the type and amount of data you want to transfer, the temporary file can be huge, the exporting very slow and you only get the visible data so you can lose methods (because they can rely on internal hidden members which can't be copied).

An alternative would be to simply rebuild the history in the current session as follows:

````
[Microsoft.Powershell.PSConsoleReadLine]::ClearHistory()
$nulhist=($histfile=(Get-PSReadLineOption).HistorySavePath)+".NUL"
Set-PSReadLineOption -historysavepath $nulhist
(gc -raw $histfile) -split "[^```r]`r?`n" | foreach {[Microsoft.Powershell.PSConsoleReadline]::AddToHistory($_) }
Set-PSReadLineOption -HistorySavePath $histfile
Remove-Item $nulhist
````

The idea is that we clear this session's in memory history (`ClearHistory()` doesn't affect the history file) and then add the entire contents of the history file back in again, making sure that commands which span multiple lines remain intact. The temporary file is required because adding a session history entry also adds it to the history file. Unfortunately, this also isn't particularly fast but at least it maintains your variables.